While parsing string returned from API using JObject.Parse, getting invalid character encountered error
I am receiving a response from API in below string format:
"{\"nbf\":2024-04-17T16:28:14.509+0800, \"iat\":2024-04-17T16:28:14.509+0800, \"iss\":\"https://google.com\" }"

When I am trying to use JObject.Parse() method then I am getting below error:
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: T. Path 'nbf'"

The property nbf appears to have the value that is a ISO date time; but JSON has no support for date time values.
Such a date time needs to be serialised as a string (ie. in double quotes).
Likely the invalid character is the first - because the prior characters in the value would otherwise be a number,.
For the full details of the JSON format see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259 section 3.

This response I am getting from External Party. Anyway we can add double quotes to the date ?

Hardcode a response with and without the correction to confirm. Then report the bug to the third party: but plan on having to work around the "not-JSON" response.

your best approach is to insert " before serializing.
P.S. I wrote fast, code can be refactored for better...
void Main()
{
    string json = "{\"nbf\":2024-04-17T16:28:14.509+0800, \"iat\":2024-04-17T16:28:14.509+0800, \"iss\":\"https://google.com\" }";
    json = FixJson(json);
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json).Dump();
}

string FixJson(string j)
{
    j = ReplaceValue(j, "nbf", 28);
    j = ReplaceValue(j, "iat", 28);
    return j.ToString();
}

public string ReplaceValue(string s, string value, int len)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int startposition = s.IndexOf(value)+5;
    sb.Append(s.Substring(0, startposition));
    sb.Append($"\"{s.Substring(startposition, len)}\"");
    var last = s.Substring(startposition + len);
    sb.Append(last);
    return sb.ToString();
}

public class Test
{
    public DateTimeOffset nbf { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset iat { get; set; }
    public string iss { get; set; }

}



